# Possible to have Angular ng-if with multiple conditions, some bound once, some two-way?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, bindonce

My question is not whether or not you can use multiple conditions in `ng-if`, but rather whether or not it's possible to have `ng-if` with only some conditions bound once, while others watch for updates?

As a simple example, if I want to bind the name once, but have a toggle state property that I want to watch for updates: `<span ng-if="::page.name === 'something' && page.viewEnabled">Correct page, and the view is enabled!</span>`

I would expect that a toggle to `page.viewEnabled` assuming it's a boolean, would cause the span to disappear. That does not appear to be the case (using Angular 1.3.11).

Does the one-time binding on `::page.name` setup the entire expression as being bound once?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** What I'm curious about is if you have multiple conditions in the same `ng-if`, one being bound once, while another is not. What I'm seeing is that if you have one that is bound once, the other changing will not affect the `ng-if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this out, and can confirm that you can in fact `bind-once` to an `ngIf` statement. Consider the following example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/m32BBBYlNffxTfggb33g?p=preview

Say your UI is programmatically updating an array of `fruits`, and let's say we have two `ngIf` expressions: one uses `bind-once`, the other is bound normally (i.e twice):

```
<div ng-if="::fruits.length > 3">More than three fruits!</div>
<div ng-if="fruits.length > 3">More than three fruits!</div>
```

If we begin adding to this array, we'll note that only the second `ngIf` expression is triggered when the condition is met:

[image]

**UPDATE**

So it looks as though the original question was more geared toward putting two (2) expressions in an `ngIf`, but where one expression utilizes `bind-once`. And interestingly enough, neither of the statements fire (see below), which is a bit surprising, which would seem to indicate you cannot combine one and two-way bound expressions. In the first `ngIf`, I would have expected the very first condition to have been evaluated truthfully, then short-circuit since it doesn't need to evaluate the second expression, which happens to be bound once. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Plunkr has been updated.

```
  <div ng-if="fruits.length > 3 || ::fruits.length > 3">1.) More than three fruits!</div>
  <div ng-if="::fruits.length > 3 || fruits.length > 3">2.) More than three fruits!</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my initial question wasn't terribly clear. What I'm asking is if you can have say, two values in the nf-if statement, one of which is bound once, another watching for updates. But both in the SAME statement. What I'm seeing as a result is that if one is bound once, the other (even when updated) will not affect the ng-if.